# Getting the ID of inserted item

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I have a query as such:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[bill](bruto, waiterid, reversalid, number, ddate, tableid, total, printed, posplace, guestid, numberofguests, closedtime, methodofpaymentid, realdate) " +
                    "VALUES (@bruto, @waiterid, 0, 0, @ddate, 1, @total, 'True', 0, 0, 0, @closedtime, @methodofpaymentid, @realtime) " +
                    "SELECT id";
//+ lines of cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue(...,...);
```

But once I try to execute the query with:

```
int newId = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

I get that id is not identified (even though it Does exist).

If I try changing the `SELECT` to `[dbo].[bill].id`, I get the error

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.bill.id" could not be bound.

I also tried making it `SELECT MAX(id)` (as this is the closest thing to a scalar), but yet again, I get the unidentified error.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: could you please post all `SELECT` statement in Q

Comment: @tinka this is it, I just need the ID and if you mean all of the SELECT queries I have for that table, that would be over 100 statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

just after your insert query and it will give you the identity of the last insert row. Check the MSDN for details on [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope.

Comment: this pretty much did it. Thanks, Rahul! I'll accept the answer when I'm able to (~ 9 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement may contain an OUTPUT INSERTED. clause.

This could look like this:

```
INSERT .... OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
```

And executed with your execute scalar call.

Comment: I did try that, actually, but with no success, unfortunately. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: That sounds strange, because I did it this way several times

Comment: From what I've read from other StackOverflow questions, it did work for some people, yes, but it looks like it depends on what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Seems to be first found in SQL Server 2008